# Acer Helios 300 doesn't recognize 16 GB of RAM?

Tags: windows-10, memory

According to Task Manager, I can get a little more than 5000 MB before I get to the 100% RAM used mark, and other softwares claim to only have access to 5000 MB of RAM - and I [supposedly] have 16GB installed! I tried switching the two 8 GB sticks of RAM around, but aside from that I'm a little lost on how to identify the problem here. This has been happening for a while, but today this caused a software I was using to crash (first image). What's bizarre/beyond my knowledge is that on the performance tab, it shows that 8 GB is being used (second image) - but I don't have any other programs open! Surely Windows 10 doesn't need to reserve 8 GB of RAM simply to run? I'd be very grateful for any pointers or help with this issue!

[image]
[image]

## Edit

Reading the responses so far, I think there are several aspects of this issue that I don't understand - namely what Task Manager is actually showing. Thanks to @Mokubai's answer, I downloaded a copy of 64-bit Rhinoceros 3D which should increase its memory usage from that end, however I'm still confused as to why the values in Task Manager should be why they are...

For example, here's how I understand the following snapshots: out of the 16 GBs of RAM my system has, 64% of it is being used by various programs - at least 10 GBs of RAM (confirmed in the 3rd image below). Chrome (which is 64-bit) is using about 30% of what I assume is the 16 GBs of RAM, to which I would deduce that Chrome is using about 4.8 GB of memory. However, if I change percents to values, Task Manager shows that Chrome is using about 2.2 GBs of memory. Thus, with this understanding, I would assume that my system only recognizes about 7.3 GB of memory (using the values for Chrome given by Task Manager, as 30% of 7.3 is about 2.2).

Am I misunderstanding anything here?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Comment: Your screenshot does not show the relevant memory performance view. Did you perhaps disable the page file or is it very small?

Comment: You should switch to 64-bit versions of applications if you want to use all your memory. 32-bit applications are limited.

Comment: @DanielB The first screenshot shows that, in the Task Manager, 45% of RAM = 2673.5 MB, and so my understanding is that it thinks 100% of RAM is 5945 MB of RAM... what do you mean by "relevant memory performance"? I don't think I consciously disabled anything

Comment: Your second screenshot of Task Manager shows the CPU performance view. It is not relevant for the problem at hand.

Comment: @DanielB My apologies there, I was only looking at the values under "Memory" and didn't even look at the main window. My edit to the question adds an image with that fixed

Comment: The "percent" of memory used may be doing some creative accountancy and including figures not shown elsewhere. It might be that the 2.2GB is *actual used* while the percent is *commit charge* which is entirely different (might use but not actually *in* use). Your actual system use from the performance tab is showing the correct usage. Ignore the 2.2GB = 30% because there is definitely something not quite right there.

Comment: @Mokubai So, is Task Manager off regarding how much memory Chrome is using? Is that just an error in calculation then?

Answer (score 1):

Your copy of Rhinocerous is a 32-bit application. Between the kernel and graphics card 32-bit applications *might* manage to use maybe 3GB of memory and you are pretty much at that limit.

The application crashing has nothing to do with any perceived problem with your system having 16GB of RAM. The problem is that 32-bit applications can only see up to 4GB of RAM maximum.

You can have multiple 32-bit applications and between them your system will be able to share all your RAM, but any individual program can only use 3-4GB. Within that 4GB space a program may only be able to use about 2GB unless they are "large address aware" and can use more of the 4GB space.

You should update your program to a 64-bit copy if it is available.

The error stating that "Windows" is out of memory is slightly erroneous. On a 32-bit system Windows limited the *entire* system to one single 4GB space and so the error *might* have been relevant but is still mainly the application having a problem. On a 64-bit operating system that error is wrongly attributing the fault to Windows when the memory limit is due to the application itself.

Comment: Thank you for this information, I wasn't aware of this! However, I'm still lost regarding the available RAM in general, as the first screenshot shows that, in the Task Manager, 45% of RAM = 2673.5 MB, and so my understanding is that it thinks 100% of RAM is 5945.1 MB of RAM...

Comment: No, **the program itself** thinks 100% of RAM is 2675MB because it is a 32-bit program that is limited to 2GB of usable RAM in a 4GB address space. The 32-bit program is completely unable to see anything more. It is a limit of 32-bit programs. That *other programs* can use more is a feature of virtual memory isolating programs into their own address spaces so that every program effectively has its own 4GB space. The available RAM is what Windows says it is, 32-bit programs are incapable of "seeing" more than 4GB and can only use ~2GB of it themselves, the rest being shared with the OS kernel.

Comment: In your mind you need to separate the **program error** you are seeing from the operating system memory usage (45%) because they are **not** related.

Comment: @IbrahimMahmoud Column headers show percentage of **total** resource consumption, not per process.

Comment: @gronostaj Whoops, that was a mistake on my part, you guys are right - I usually disregard the rest of the processes that show up in Task Manager because their memory usage is so low in comparison, and so when I added that comment that's what was going on in my head. My edit to the question should outline my issue more clearly!

Answer (score 1):

@Mokubai's answer has a complete explanation of this situation. In short, it's a limitation of 32-bit programs.

Ideally you should use the 64-bit version of the software. If it's not available for some reason, you can try to use the [4GB Patch](https://ntcore.com/?page_id=371). It will attempt to modify the EXE to increase the memory limit to 4 GB rather than the default 2 GB.

Here's an explanation how it works from the linked website:

> On x86 applications have 2GB of virtual memory out of 4GB (the other 2GB are reserved for the system). On x64 these two other GB can now be accessed by 32bit applications. In order to achieve this, a flag has to be set in the file’s internal format.

Why is the application using 2.6 GB if it should be limited to 2 GB? I'm just guessing, but I think it's an overhead of WOW64 - the platform that lets you run 32-bit software on 64-bit Windows.

Comment: Thank you for that link and explanation! I'll definitely try that with some of my 32-bit applications I have